# parse json, populate collection view Swift 4.2

Tags: json, swift, xcode

This is too simple but I am lost. I am still new to swift really.

I need to parse the downloaded `json` ( localized file in the Xcode project ) and populate the data to a `CollectionView`.

```
enum Response{
    case success(Data)
    case error(Error)
}

// struct follows the json
 struct InformationFromJson: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}



class MYJSON {
    public func downloadMYJSON(_ completion: @escaping (Response) -> ()) {

            guard let bundle = Bundle(identifier: MYJSON.bundleId), let path = bundle.path(forResource: "data", ofType: "json"), let data = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path)) else {
                completion(Response.error(NSError(domain: MYJSON.bundleId, code: MYJSON.bundleErrorCode, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : MYJSON.bundleError])))
                return
            }
            completion(Response.success(data))  
    }
}
```

So, without totally changing the function call, how do I parse the json? It's downloaded so far from the function, but I don't see how to even add a print statement to test, without getting errors because of the guard statement , the way it is.

I need to simple populate a `cellForRowAt`:

I never saw nested guard like this, so it got me. I am used to seeing the let statements separated so you can put print statements to at least see if things are getting downloaded or parsed.

Answer (score 0):

You can decode your `json` by passing `data`, whatever you get from

```
let data = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))     

guard let decoded = try? JSONDecoder().decode(InformationFromJson.self, from: data) else { 
    return 
}
```

Comment: OMG It's that stinking easy? Where would I put the guard let decoded statement? Before or after.  completion(Response.success(data))

Comment: I don't what to do with the decoder statement. How do I grab the json into another swift file? I have the struct, but does the guard statement automatically attach the parsed json data to the struct?

Comment: No, you have to take one variable and need to assign parsed value to it. And use it in any class you want to use.

Comment: Thank you Chankya. I built a struct with variables matching the json model. And Inunderstand the functions download the data. But what I am missing in my head is a method to assign the downloaded data to the struct model, so I can use the data in any class. Do I call those functions in say, cell for item? Any help would be awesome! Thank you!

Comment: I am still lost on this. I am trying decode, but everywhere I put that, I get errors. I am lost. Please help.

Comment: let data = MusicLibrary.downloadMusicLibraryDefinition()
   
let jsonData = try? JSONDecoder().decode(PlayList.self, from: data)

Comment: What is problem please let me know?

Comment: I don't know where to put the json decoder method. I feel so lost. Im sorry.

Comment: PLEASE help!! Where do I put the guard let decoded statement? I am not supposed to modify the nested guard or the entire download function method. I am honestly lost here.